# Tortoisesvn auto resolve conflicts on folder?

Tags: tortoisesvn, conflict, resolve

is it possible to set a 'rule' that tells TortoiseSVN to automatically resolve conflicts on a specific folder?

ie. we have a shared resources folder - "/shared" that we use to store our latest bin files in.  when we do a local build, the local bin files in that folder gets overwritten.

next time we do an svn update on that folder the update should pull the latest bin files from SVN and overwrite the previously locally-built bin files but this will throw a conflict because the files are binary and cannot be merged (and, should not be merged anyway)

we would like to setup a rule that tells tortoise to always "resolve using theirs" on that /shared folder ("svn update -R --accept theirs-full")

Comment: Why are your bin files in Subversion at all? If the source is under version management, you don't need the compiled binaries as well. You can archive them separately on disk and back that up.

Answer (score 0):

There's a SVN misuse here. If the files should not be merged as you said, the directory should be set to ignore all .bin files (svn:ignore). It doesn't make sense keep in version control binary files that are changed frequently causing so much collisions.

In your place, I would delete all .bin files from this folder. If it's really necessary to keep the files versioned, I would create a directory and place these .bin files in there, avoiding frequent changing.

But if you **really** want to keep the files as they are, I recommend you to write client-side hooks for post-update events. See [TortoiseSVN Docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html) for more information.